# Is there a way to programmatically detect the level of AES encryption in an encrypted string? (128 vs 192 vs 256)

Tags: c#, aes

So if there is a string that has been encrypted, are there bytes or a method we can run to detect its level of encryption?  I am looking for a C# solution.

Comment: No, It will be against the encryption rule.

Comment: If you could distinguish this fact (especially given that they all use the same block size) it would mean the encryption algorithm was broken.

Comment: Only by detecting exceptions.  The algorithm has some error checking and you will get exceptions from the errors.  But only by trying to decrypt a message will you detect failures.

Comment: Thank you, guys.